# How to convert string to date using pyspark?

Tags: string, date, pyspark, error-handling, type-conversion

I want to convert this format, which is an string "month_year"

"2023/03"

to date format (desidered output)

2023/03

I tryed this :

```
df= df.withColumn("month_year", to_date(col("month_year"), "yyyy/MM"))
df= df.withColumn("month_year", col("month_year").cast("date"))
```

But it does not work,

Any suggestions?

Comment: only `yyyy-MM-dd` is acceptable `DateType` format for spark. all other formats are considered strings.

Answer (score 0):

spark default date format is `yyyy-MM-dd` and using `to_date()` function we don't have date in the month_year column.

- So spark gives default `01` as the date after converting to date type.
- We don't have to cast to date after using to_date function as this function results `date` type.

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df = spark.createDataFrame([('2023/03',)],['month_year'])
df.withColumn("month_year",to_date(col("month_year"),"yyyy/MM")).printSchema()
df.withColumn("month_year",to_date(col("month_year"),"yyyy/MM")).show(10,False)

#root
# |-- month_year: date (nullable = true)

#+----------+
#|month_year|
#+----------+
#|2023-03-01|
#+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation, I understood... What do you suggest? convert that date to Python?? the reason is because that date format yyyy/MM I need to use like an input which requires as date format with structure yyyy/MM

Comment: didn't understand well but if u require this as `yyyy/MM` format then keep the data same as `yyyy/MM` format..